# how to build binary tree from post order

Tags: algorithm, f#

I find an example build from preorder, how about how to build binary tree from post
order ?

i edit as following, is it correct

```
type BinaryTree = 
    | Nil 
    | Node of NodeType * BinaryTree * BinaryTree

let rec buildBSTfromPostOrder (l:NodeType list) = 
match l with
| [] -> Nil
| [a] -> Node(a, Nil, Nil)
| h::t -> 
    let b = Node(h, buildBSTfromPostOrder(t), buildBSTfromPostOrder(t))
    let smaller = 
               t 
               |> Seq.takeWhile (fun n -> n < h) 
               |> Seq.toList
    let bigger = 
               t 
               |> Seq.skipWhile (fun n -> n < h) 
               |> Seq.toList
    b


let input = [10; 1; 2; 2; 1; 50]
```

Comment: Your code implies there is one more detail which is not mentioned in the question. It seems this is a post order of a binary *search* tree - meaning you know what its in-order traversal already. Is it indeed the case?

Comment: @amit, I guess the BST in `buildBSTfromPostOrder` implies that it is a binary search tree :)

Comment: You are not using `smaller` and `bigger`, do you know where they should go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, if you want reconstruct some binary tree from streams (lists) must use at least two.

There is a Haskell version (very closed to F#)

```
post [] _ = [] 
post (x:xs) ys = post (take q xs) (take q ys) ++         -- left
                 post (drop q xs) (drop (q + 1) ys) ++   -- right
                 [x]                                     -- node
    where (Just q) = elemIndex x ys
```

That function reconstruct post order from pre and in order. Can be adapted to other versions.
(The keys should be uniques too)

If your tree is ordered (BST) then, simply populate tree with keys.

To populate your BST, you can write

```
let rec insert tree n =
    match tree with
    | Nil -> Node(n, Nil, Nil)
    | Node(x, left, right) -> if n < x then Node(x, insert left n, right)
                                       else Node(x, left, insert right n)

let populate xs = Seq.fold insert Nil xs
```

example

```
let rec show tree =
    match tree with
    | Nil -> printf ""
    | Node(x, left, right) -> do printf "[%d;" x
                                 show left
                                 printf ";"
                                 show right
                                 printf "]"

do show <| populate [|1;6;4;8;2;|]
```